# Ambiguity and motivation for the definition of a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear operator is defined as a transformation $T:V \to W$ such that $V=W$. I was just given the zero transformation and the transformation $(x,y) \to (x,0)$ as examples of linear operators. Wouldn't this suggest that $V=0$ for any vector space $V$ and that $R^2 = R$ or am I misunderstanding the definition? Does, for example, $T:V \to W$ mean that $T$ maps from $V$ to any subspace of $W$? If the answer is yes, why is this the accepted definition?

Edit: It seems that the range of a function $f:V \to W$ is always a subset of the co-domain $W$. Does this mean that any transformation from a higher dimension to a lower dimension is an operator? For example, the statement $T:R^3 \to R^3$ is equivalent to the statement $T: R^3 \to R$ if the range of $T$ is $R$.

Comment: That's a very strange definition. Where did you find this definition?

Comment: `such that V=W` Please quote the source of that definition. The common one only requires that $f(z_1 + z_2) = f(z_1) + f(z_2)$ and $f(\lambda z) = \lambda f(z)$ for any scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: That is the definition for a linear operator (not a linear transformation). That's is how its defined on everywhere from Wikipedia to my textbook (Axler)

Comment: I don't think that's common terminology. See for example [Linear transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearTransformation.html), [Linear operator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearOperator.html). Note in particular this part: "*A linear transformation may or may not be injective or surjective*".

Comment: It's not just any transformation, but a linear transformation $V \rightarrow V$, that we call a linear operator, and as b2coutts said in his answer, we don't require it to be surjective. But I'm still confused. How did you get $V=0$?

Comment: I was told that the zero transformation is actually an operator (I don't know if that's right).

Comment: Again, please quote the sources of your definitions. On a quick search, I couldn't find *one* which said that a linear operator (or transformation) *must* be surjective.

Comment: @dxiv That's part of my question. I'm asking if a linear operator must be surjective. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No, it does *not* have to be surjective, and the $0$ map is certainly a linear one. `I'm asking if a linear operator must be surjective` Then you should edit the original question to actually ask that. The way it's worded now `defined as ... such that V = W` it sounds like you *posit* that it must be surjective.

Comment: @dxiv That is the definition of a linear operator though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map look at the third line.The issue lies in the difference between viewing $W$ as the codomain vs. the range. It seems that $W$ almost always means the codomain, so $V=W$ does not imply surjectivity. I hope we both learned something today!

Comment: You misunderstand that line. It says that $V=W$ but it does *not* say or imply that $range f = W$. Quite the contrary, it notes right away that "*A linear map always maps linear subspaces onto linear subspaces* (***possibly of a lower dimension***)". See also @AOrtiz's updated answer, which attempts to clarify the same confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are misunderstanding the definition of a *function*. The notation $T:V\to W$ means that $T$ is a function whose domain is $V$ and whose codomain is $W$. Formally, a function $f:A \to B$ is a binary relation such that for each $a \in A$, there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$, or $f(a) = b$. These functions can be surjective, in which case the range is equal to the codomain. In general, functions are not surjective, in which case the range of the function is a proper subset of the codomain.

A linear transformation $T$ is a function between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, where $V$ and $W$ are not necessarily the same set, such that $T$ satisfies some additional properties. Namely, it is *linear* in the sense that for $x,y \in V$, $T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y)$ and for $c$ in the underlying field, $T(cx) = cT(x)$.

The special term *linear operator* is used to distinguish a linear transformation that maps elements from a vector space $V$ *to the same space* $V$. Symbolically, $T:V\to V$. The function $0: V \to V$ that sends each $v \in V$ to $0 \in V$ is a (linear) operator because the domain and the codomain are the same set; it is not surjective. In general, neither linear transformations nor linear operators are the zero transformation, as the linear operator $(x,y) \mapsto (x, 0)$ shows us. In general, linear transformations are *not surjective*. Just consider $(x,y) \mapsto (x, 0)$ as an example of a linear transformation that isn't surjective.

Comment: The map from $v \in V$ to the zero vector is certainly a linear transformation, but I too am confused to whether its a linear operator. Also, are you saying that $(x,y) \to (x,0)$ is not a linear operator?

Comment: @orange_juice, I edited my answer to address some of your questions in the comment. Notice that the map $f:(x,y) \mapsto (x, 0)$ is linear because it satisfies $f(\vec x + \vec y) = f(\vec x) + f(\vec y)$ and $f(c\vec x) = cf(\vec x)$.

Answer (score 1):

When we say $T : V \to W$, we don't necessarily mean that $T$ is surjective, only that for every $v$, we have $T(v) \in W$. In other words, it is fine if there are things in $W$ that $T$ does not map anything to; we can still say $T : V \to W$. This is true for functions in general.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Do you know why this is? Why don't we define $T:V \to V$ to mean that $T$ is surjective?

Comment: I think if we did that you'd find yourself writing things like $T : V \to T(V)$ very often. It's often annoying to have to specify precisely what the range of your function is, especially if it doesn't matter.

But ultimately it's an arbitrary choice of notation, and there are cases where either will be more convenient.

Comment: One of the upshots of the more flexible definition is that the set of all linear operators on $V$ forms a vector space in its own right; in fact, if you take the composition of linear operators as a kind of multiplication, it defines a (noncommutative) associative algebra. Functional analysis and the various flavours of noncommutative geometry get *enormous* mileage out of these very simple observations.